# barButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") returns nil in ios 12

Tags: null

I am trying to get view for UIBarButtonItem to add badge to it. It works fine in IOS 13 to 16. but in ios 12, it returns nil for below code

if let value = barButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView {. // <<<< RETURN nil
xxxx
}

I need to get the view to be used for adding badge circle.

Thanks.